# i am trying to make a function that check for errors, but i get only one or two errors which is wrong

Tags: javascript

```
    var checkErrors = 0;

   // Check for mistakes function
    function yourResult() {
        let checkErrors = 0;
        let textEnterd = testArea.value;
        let orginTextMatch = originText.substring(0, textEnterd.length);
        if (textEnterd.length == originText.length || textEnterd == originText) {
            if (textEnterd != orginTextMatch) {
                ++checkErrors;
            }
            theResult.innerHTML **strong text** = "You did " + checkErrors + " mistakes.";
        }
    }

    testArea.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        yourResult();

    }, false);
```

// "return"

This is a test typing project, i am stuck at the yourResult function, i cant get the desire errors.

Comment: Looks like you forgot a loop somewhere. But without more information, we really can't tell.

Comment: i can post the whole page if you would like to

Comment: Please only the relevant parts that your function is supposed to use. See how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake is that the error count is reset after each stroke.
So put that outside and you can match the characters as they're typed.
It's not far off, so you can try this instead:

```
// Put check errors variable outside of the function to keep count between the key strokes
// Reset to 0 when starting the test over
let checkErrors = 0;

function yourResult(){
    let textEnterd = testArea.value;
    let charPos = textEnterd.length;

    // Match the characters at their positions. If they don't match, add them up
    if (charPos > 0 && textEnterd.charAt(charPos) != originText.charAt(charPos)) {
        ++checkErrors;
    }
    theResult.innerHTML = "You did " + checkErrors + " mistakes.";
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped.

Comment: Dimitriy what debuggers did you use to test my code? if any please let me know.

Comment: I only used Chrome Developer Tools console (F12). Modified the variables to prevent errors and checked the logic there. Then placed the variables back to work with your original script. If you want to use a debugger, I would use chrome as well. (Under 'Sources' tab in developer tools)